# Why can fread() not work (skipping bytes) under Msys/MinGw?

Tags: c, windows, mingw, fread, xuggle

Trying to build Xuggler under Windows. Xuggler is core native code functions wrapped into         Java for sound processing purposes (including ffmpeg).

My Windows is x64 Win 7 prof, but all used libraries are 32bit. I am running build procedure under MinGW/MSys, from under Msys shell with the followinf script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/C/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Java/jdk1.6.0_25
export XUGGLE_HOME=/C/Xuggler

PATH=$XUGGLE_HOME/bin:/C/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/bin:/d/APPS/msysgit/msysgit/bin/git:/D/APPS/MinGW/bin:/bin:/D/APPS/apa    che-ant-1.8.2/bin:/D/Users/Dims/Design/MinGW/Util:$PATH
ant -Dbuild.m64=no run-tests
```

Ant target contains some tests at the end, which give an error. The error follows

```
 [exec] Running 6 tests..
 [exec] In StdioURLProtocolHandlerTest::testRead:
 [exec] ../../../../../../../../../test/csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/io/StdioURLProtocolHandlerTest.cpp:108: Error: Expected (4546420 == totalBytes), found (4546420 != 1042)
 [exec] In StdioURLProtocolHandlerTest::testReadWrite:
 [exec] ../../../../../../../../../test/csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/io/StdioURLProtocolHandlerTest.cpp:185: Error: Expected (4546420 == totalBytes), found (4546420 != 1042)
 [exec] In StdioURLProtocolHandlerTest::testSeek:
 [exec] ../../../../../../../../../test/csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/io/StdioURLProtocolHandlerTest.cpp:139: Error: Expected (4546420 == totalBytes), found (4546420 != 1042)
 [exec] .
 [exec] Failed 3 of 6 tests
 [exec] Success rate: 50%
 [exec] FAIL: xugglerioTestStdioURLProtocolHandler.exe
```

**UPDATE 1**

The test code is follows:

```
int32_t totalBytes = 0;
do {
    unsigned char buf[2048];
    retval = handler->url_read(buf, (int)sizeof(buf));
    if (retval > 0)
         totalBytes+= retval;
} while (retval > 0);
VS_TUT_ENSURE_EQUALS("", 4546420, totalBytes);
```

While the `url_read` code is follows:

```
int
StdioURLProtocolHandler :: url_read(unsigned char* buf, int size)
{
    if (!mFile)
        return -1;
    return (int) fread(buf, 1, size, mFile);
}
```

I don't understand, under what circumstances it can return 1042??? May be 64 bits play here somehow?

**UPDATE 2**

I printed out filename used and it was

```
d:/......./../../../test/fixtures/testfile.flv
```

the path is correct, but started with `d:/` not with `/d/`

Can this play a role under Msys?

**UPDATE 3**

I have compared the readen bytes with real content of the test file and found, that fread() skips some bytes for some reason. Don't know which bytes yet, probably these are CR/LF

**UPDATE 4**

Not related with CR/LF I guess.

Original bytes are

```
46 4C 56 01 05 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 12 00 00 F4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 0A 6F 6E 4D 65 74 61 44 61 74 61 08 00 00 ...
```

readen bytes are

```
46 4C 56 15 00 09 00 00 12 00 F4 00 00 00 02 0A 6F 6E 4D 65 74 61 44 61 74 61 80 00 B0 86 47 57 26 17 46 96 F6 E0 40 62 ...
```

This is FLV file begin. I don't understand the ptinciple of corruption.

How can `01 05 00 00` transform to just `15`???

**UPDATE 5**

File opening done like following

```
void
StdioURLProtocolHandlerTest :: testRead()
{
  StdioURLProtocolManager::registerProtocol("test");
  URLProtocolHandler* handler = StdioURLProtocolManager::findHandler("test:foo", 0,0);
  VS_TUT_ENSURE("", handler);

  int retval = 0;
  retval = handler->url_open(mSampleFile, URLProtocolHandler::URL_RDONLY_MODE);
  VS_TUT_ENSURE("", retval >= 0);

  int32_t totalBytes = 0;
  printf("Bytes:\n");
  do {
     //...
```

url_open() function follows:

```
int StdioURLProtocolHandler :: url_open(const char *url, int flags)
{
  if (!url || !*url)
    return -1;
  reset();
  const char * mode;

  switch(flags) {
    case URLProtocolHandler::URL_RDONLY_MODE:
      mode="r";
      break;
    case URLProtocolHandler::URL_WRONLY_MODE:
      mode="w";
      break;
    case URLProtocolHandler::URL_RDWR_MODE:
          mode="r+";
          break;
        default:
      return -1;
  }

  // The URL MAY contain a protocol string.  Find it now.
  char proto[256];
  const char* protocol = URLProtocolManager::parseProtocol(proto, sizeof(proto), url);
  if (protocol)
  {
    size_t protoLen = strlen(protocol);
    // skip past it
    url = url + protoLen;
    if (*url == ':' || *url == ',')
      ++url;
  }
//  fprintf(stderr, "protocol: %s; url: %s; mode: %s\n", protocol, url, mode);
  mFile = fopen(url, mode);
  if (!mFile)
    return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you opening that file?

Comment: See update 5. Looks not suspicious.

Comment: Looks suspicious. No "b" in the open mode.

Comment: But how can it work under linux then? May be somewhere defaults can be set?

Comment: It will work both on Windows and Linux with a "b". Linux doesn't care one way or another (the flag is ignored, binary is read), Windows does potentially a lot of translation.

Comment: Yes thanks, you are right, found it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fixed in the GIT repository on the cross_compile branch as of today.  I will roll this into tip of tree later this week / early next week.

Now the stdio handler opens all files as binary.

Comment: Thanks. Is it recommended to user `cross_compile` to compile for Windows? I.e. I can run compiler on Linux but will get binary for Windows, right?

Comment: master now contains this fix and the pre-built jar file distributed on our ivy repo contains all os.  you will NOT get windows builds by default if you build in Linux.  You will need to enable cross-compiling (search the blog for how).